# Ignore certain text in reg ex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am looking to write a reg ex that picks up certain definitions in a contract that are separated by quotation marks.  However, some of the definitions contain quotation marks w/in the definition.

I'm unsure how to write a reg ex that will not stop at the first quotation marks, but rather the second instance.

Here is what I have for the following text -- ^\s*\"Consolidated Interest Expense\"([^"]*)

"Consolidated Interest Expense" means, with reference to any period, without duplication, the interest expense (including without limitation interest expense under Capital Lease Obligations that is treated as interest) for such period as is defined in "The Agreement" set forth herein. Consolidated Interest Expense shall be determined for such period on a pro forma basis as if such acquisition or disposition, and any related incurrence or repayment of Indebtedness, had occurred at the beginning of such period.

"Consolidated Net Income" means, with reference to any period, the net income (or loss) of the Company and its Subsidiaries 
calculated in accordance with GAAP on a consolidated basis (without duplication) for such period• provided that there shall be excluded

I'd love a reg ex that captures the entire "consolidated interest expense" and doesn't stop at "The Agreement" but rather stops at the next definition -- "consolidated net income"

Comment: Are you really trying to come up with a regex that just matches until the end of a paragraph?

Also, what language are you trying to write your regex in?

Comment: I'm trying to come up with one that picks up the entire definition -- usually from quotes to quotes but sometimes quotes are within the definition.  Also, many of the definitions run multiple paragraphs, that's why the quote to quote usually works rather than by paragraph...just not here.

Comment: I think chris here is a noob at regex, my guess is he's trying to use PCRE regex for context.

Comment: @Chris what language are you trying to use this regex in? What's the context? Different languages/tools have different style regexes?

Comment: Also, try `(?s)^\s*"Consolidated Interest Expense"(.*?)(?=\n"[^"]*"|\z)` if your are using PCRE. See https://regex101.com/r/kNfpeE/1

Comment: great, that worked Wiktor.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex and capture the text till end of paragraph before `"Consolidated Net Income"` like you wrote in your post,

```
^\s*"Consolidated Interest Expense"([\w\W]*\.\R)
```

Here, this part `^\s*"Consolidated Interest Expense"` you've already written so you know the line can start with optional space followed by literal `"Consolidated Interest Expense"` and then `([\w\W]*\.\R)` matches zero or more any character (`[\w\W]` is another way to write any character matching even newlines) followed by a literal dot and new line ('\R' matches any newline, windows, linux, Macox)

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/i97xhz/1)**

Let me know if this is indeed what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your response.  Please see below for what I'm seeing when typing that in...https://regex101.com/r/HSgwKo/4

Comment: @Chris: You had some space (hence not visible) before the newline which is why it didn't work. We can handle it by placing `\s*` before `\R`. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/HSgwKo/6)

Comment: @Chris: Happy to help :) Please consider marking the answer as accepted as that will reward you +2 rep and may help other people looking for similar answer quickly and easily.